# Classic ASP assign class object to array

Tags: arrays, class, vbscript, asp-classic

Having a legacy Classic ASP project and need to do the following. I have created a class:

```
Class MeView
Private m_x
Public Property Get X()
    X = m_x
End Property

Public Property Let X(value)
    m_x = value
End Property

Private m_y
Public Property Get Y()
    Y = m_y
End Property

Public Property Let Y(value)
    m_y = value
End Property
```

End Class

Now I define variables:

```
    Dim Me
Dim MeList()
Dim index : index = 0
```

Then I loop through a resultset and assign values to the Me Class. After that, I put the Me object in an array.

```
          if not rs.eof then
        while not rs.EOF
            Redim Preserve MeList(index)
            Set Me = New MeView
            Me.X = Sanitize(rs("X"))
            Me.Y = Sanitize(rs("Y"))
            Set MeList(index) = Me
            index = index + 1
            rs.Movenext
        wend
      end if
```

So far so good, if I check the UBound of MeList, it's showing the correct value. The problem arises here:

```
Dim i
For i = 0 to Ubound(MeList)
    Set Me = New MeView
    Me = MeList(i)
    Response.write Me(i).X
Next
```

I get the following error
**Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' 
Object required: '[undefined]'**

I'm looking at this already for 2 days and just can't see what the issue is.
Any input to point me in the right direction, would be much appreciated.

Comment: You lose the entire content of MeList when you do Redim. If you want to keep the content, you have to do Redim Preserve MeList(index).

Comment: This will not get as far as that error, `Me` is reserved & the class names MeView/ViewMe do not match ...

Comment: Hi, not the best choice, I agree, but Me is just an example I typed down MeView/ViewMe is just a typo

Comment: Ineed, I missed the Preserved option. I changed it now and now I get **Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01b6' 
Object doesn't support this property or method**. I edited my initial question as it's a valid point

Comment: If you use `Set MeList(index) = Me` then, why don't you use `Set Me = MeList(i)`?

Comment: That was it: I overlooked it, thanks for pointing out the obvious!

Comment: @MCND which is what I thought before until Regis pointed out the `Preserve` missing. Most of the time, `Object Not Set` or `Object Required` are due to a missing `Set <object_ref> = <object>`.